# how to change long format number in php?

Tags: php

I want to ask something about number `function` on **PHP**. How to change `1.7849313424115E+16` format into `17849313424115340` ?

My problem is, i use an API and return value is `1.7849313424115E+16`, but i need `17849313424115340` format for another process. i can't change API for output code, so i think i must "convert" the output value. Is it possible to do?

I've tried to use `round()`, `intval()`, etc. but i still not get a clue.Any ideas or suggest? Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Literally took your question title and the very first result is the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `number_format` function for this.

```
  number_format(1.7849313424115E+16,0,'','')
```

Comment: Glad to know you that it helps you.Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `number_format` function in PHP.

```
echo number_format(1.7849313424115E+16);
```

It returns the following output:

```
17,849,313,424,115,000
```